# how to solve this OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, sql, memory, garbage-collection

i have the following program which goes to database and gets the value, i have excuted the query also it gives me only 47 row but when i run the same program in console mode it gives me `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

```
package com.common;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.common.Query;

public class GetColumnValuesFromDifferentTypes {
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static void printColumns(String query){
    ABIDAO abidao = new ABIDAO();
    int numberOfColumns=0,columnType = 0;
    String columnValue = "", columnName = "";
    Map<String, String> headerMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        Connection connection = abidao.getConnection();
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                headerMap = getHeader(query);
                System.out.println("====================================================================");
                System.out.println("Header Map : "+headerMap);
                System.out.println("====================================================================");
                PreparedStatement reportTablePS = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet reportTable_rst = reportTablePS.executeQuery();
                ResultSetMetaData reportTable_rsmd = reportTable_rst.getMetaData();
                numberOfColumns = reportTable_rsmd.getColumnCount();

                    int i =0;
                    while (reportTable_rst.next()) {
                            for (int columnIterator = 1; columnIterator <= numberOfColumns; columnIterator++) {
                                 columnValue = null;
                               columnName = reportTable_rsmd.getColumnName(columnIterator);
                               columnType = reportTable_rsmd.getColumnType(columnIterator);

                               if(columnType == Types.CHAR || columnType == Types.VARCHAR || columnType == Types.LONGVARCHAR)
                               {
                                   columnValue = reportTable_rst.getString(columnName);
                               }else if(columnType == Types.INTEGER || columnType == Types.BIGINT || columnType == Types.SMALLINT || columnType == Types.NUMERIC)
                               {
                                   long templong = reportTable_rst.getLong(columnName);
                                   if(!reportTable_rst.wasNull())
                                   {
                                       columnValue  = Long.toString(templong);
                                   }
                               }else if(columnType == Types.DECIMAL || columnType == Types.DOUBLE || columnType == Types.FLOAT || columnType == Types.REAL)
                               {
                                   double tempDouble1 = reportTable_rst.getDouble(columnName);
                                   if(!reportTable_rst.wasNull())
                                   {
                                       columnValue  = Double.toString(tempDouble1);
                                   }
                               } else if(columnType == Types.TIME || columnType == Types.TIMESTAMP || columnType == Types.DATE)
                               {
                                   Timestamp sqlTimeStamp = reportTable_rst.getTimestamp(columnName);
                                   if(!reportTable_rst.wasNull())
                                   {
                                       columnValue = sqlTimeStamp.toString();
                                   }
                               }
                               System.out.println("columnValue : "+columnValue);
                               System.out.println(",");

                            }
                            System.out.println("====================================================================");
                        }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                try {
                    abidao.closeConnection(connection, null, null);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
}
@SuppressWarnings({ "unused" })
public static  Map<String, String> getHeader(String query) {
    ABIDAO abidao = new ABIDAO();
    String columnName="";
    int numberOfColumns=0,rowCount=1;
    Map<String, String> headerNamesMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    Connection connection = abidao.getConnection();
    if (connection != null) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement reportTablePS = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet reportTable_rst = reportTablePS.executeQuery();
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = reportTable_rst.getMetaData();
            numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            headerNamesMap.put("SNO","SNO");
              while (reportTable_rst.next()) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
                  columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(i).toUpperCase();
                  if(!headerNamesMap.containsKey(columnName)){
                      headerNamesMap.put(columnName, columnName); 
                  }
                }
                rowCount++;
              }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                abidao.closeConnection(connection, null, null);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return headerNamesMap;
}
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String query = "";
    Map dynamicQueryMap = new HashMap();
    Query queryObj = new Query();

    try {
        dynamicQueryMap = queryObj.getComplexReportQuery();
        if(dynamicQueryMap.containsKey("query")) query = dynamicQueryMap.get("query").toString();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    printColumns(query);

}
}
```

This is the query which is return from the Query method :

```
select
pi.po_number,poi.unit_cost,pi.placed_date CreateDate,
case when isnull(pi.date_closed) then pi.scheduled_arrival_date  
else pi.date_closed end as ReceviedDate,
poi.order_quantity,poi.roll_number,p.product_sku product_name,
pc.product_category_name,poi.rec_vendor_quantity,pv.vendor_name,p.et_conversion_unit_quantity,pi.note
from
purchase_order as pi,
purchase_order_inventory as poi,
product_vendors as pv,
products AS p,
product_categories AS pc
where
pi.purchase_order_id=poi.purchase_order_id and
pc.product_category_id=p.product_category_id and
poi.product_id = p.product_id and
poi.product_category_id=pc.product_category_id and
pi.vendor_id=pv.product_vendor_id and
( ( pi.date_closed  >= '2012-01-01' and pi.date_closed <='2012-09-05 23:59:59' ) 
or ( pi.scheduled_arrival_date  >= '2012-01-01' and pi.scheduled_arrival_date <='2012-09-05 23:59:59') ) and
pi.po_type=0 
and pi.status_id = 0 and  poi.transaction_type = 0  
order by pi.po_number ;
```

what is the problem here i am facing!! please help me to find it out.

Comment: i have closed resultset,preparestament,connection,etc, and even set this `-Xms64m -Xmx256m` but still i am getting the same. :(

Comment: please show classpath when you run your application and what `queryObj.getComplexReportQuery()` do;
how much amount of data it return?

Comment: thanks guys i figured the problem, it is actually where condition is not set with the query, I am sorry for wasting all of your time. `THANKS A LOT FOR INPUTS`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to close all your resources, not just the connection. e.g. PreparedStatement.close() and ResultSet.close() If you don't do this they are retained and become a form of a memory leak.

I suggest you confirm this yourself using `jmap -histo:live {pid}` or using a memory profiler like VisualVM or YourKit.

Comment: Note: Closing the statement should also close it's `ResultSet` but I have yet to see Java code which relies on this. Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close()

Comment: i have closed resultset,preparestament,connection,etc, and even set this -Xms64m -Xmx256m but still i am getting the same. :(

Comment: In that case you need to use a memory profiler to see where you are using memory. 256M isn't that much these days. I would set it to 4g is you can.

Answer (score 1):

You should close Connection but also ResultSet and Statements to avoid memory leaks.

And don't forget to close statements and other resources before using them again.

```
Statement stmt = ...;
...
stmt.close();
stmt = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

After avoiding programatic errors to save more memory, you can try setting a specific heap size for your application by changing the configuration of your JVM. Take a look at this post: http://informix-zone.com/node/46

Answer (score 1):

The heap size also depends on shared buffer defined in your database configuration file
you have to increase your shared buffers size in database configuration files.

For monitoring heap you can use monitor tools:-

- jmap
- jmonitor